# Gradle: Show dependencies that have newer versions

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a plugin or sth. else for Gradle that informs you when there are new library versions available for a certain depedency?

Might be difficult if some libs do not stick to well-known version conventions but for the others I think it should be possible to find out!?

If there is not, any hints how to implement this feature are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such plugin ships with Gradle. There might be a third-party plugin, but I'm not aware of one. To implement this, you would iterate over a configuration's resolved dependencies (using the `configuration.resolvedConfiguration` or `configuration.incoming` API) and query some website (e.g. http://search.maven.org) or web service for latest versions. For API details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on this. If I succeed, I'll inform you if you are interested.